# Does the op-amp integrator drift error due to offset voltage and bias currents depend on the configuration inverting or non-inverting?

Tags: operational-amplifier, integrator, miller-integrator

I have made the following two circuits to check for integrator drift errors in LTSPICE.[image: Integrators]

I have grounded both inputs, so that only the offset voltage and bias currents are integrated. I expect ramps as outputs. But the outputs I get for inverting integrator has a very high slope and a non-inverting one has a lower slope. Why should that happen?
[image: Outputs of integrators]

Comment: put a resistor to the grounded input to balance the effects of the input bias currents.

Comment: When the feedback capacitor (circuit 1) causes a negative drift (red curve), the loading effect of the grounded capacitor (circuit 2) causes an opposite effect on the non-inverting input of the opamp. Hence, both effects compensate each other partly.